# SqlDataSource updating different fields with one UpdateCommand

Tags: c#, asp.net, parameters, sqldatasource

I have a `SqlDataSource` that I would like to use for updating. I would be using two similar update commands, and I was wondering how I could do this in one `SqlDataSource`. I know how to do 'normal' parameters, but I was wondering how I could change *what* was being updated as well as *how* it's being updated. Here are my statements as I would put them into the `SqlDataSource`:

```
UPDATE Part SET checkbox02 = @val WHERE partnum = @partnum

UPDATE Part SET checkbox03 = @val WHERE partnum = @partnum
```

But, I can only have one `UpdateCommand` per `SqlDataSource`.

Is it possible to do something like this:

```
UPDATE Part SET @checkbox = @val WHERE partnum = @partnum
```

where I can change `@checkbox` and have it update either `checkbox02` or `checkbox03` depending on what I set the parameter to? Determination of `@checkbox` would be happening in the code-behind.

If this is not possible, what is the best alternative to minimize code/memory usage?

**EDIT** As noted in the comments below, my original idea in the question above Is not possible. I therefore have the following addition to my question (also in the comments, moved up here for visiblity):

Could I instead do this:

```
UpdateCommand="UPDATE Part SET checkbox02 = @val02, checkbox03 = @val03 WHERE partnum = @partnum"
```

and then set the parameter that I don't want to change to the appropriate column name? For example, say I don't want to change `checkbox02` this time, so I set the `@val02` parameter to `checkbox02`

Comment: You're probably going to have to get rid of the SqlDataSource, and then use SQL queries in the code-behind via ADO.NET (SQLCommand, SQLConnection, etc.).

Comment: You **cannot** just easily parametrize table and/or column names in your SQL statement. If you want to do this, you'll need to use *dynamic SQL* (building up your SQL statement as a string and executing it) - with the usual warnings about vulnerability against SQL injection attacks and all$

Comment: It appears as if this will not work. Could I instead do this: Have `UpdateCommand="UPDATE Part SET checkbox02 = @val02, checkbox03 = @val03 WHERE partnum = @partnum"` and then set the parameter that I don't want to change to the appropriate column name? For example, say I don't want to change `chekcbox02` this time, so I set the `@val02` parameter to `checkbox02`.

Comment: @wlyles Yes, that would work.

Comment: @jadarnel27 that actually doesn't work. I tried it, but it won't convert `checkbox02` to data type `tinyint` (the checkbox data types)

Comment: That sounds like you just haven't set the type properly when declaring your parameters in the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back and cleaning things up on my profile - man this was a long time ago...

Anyway, as I recall, the solution here was to use a more custom solution with SQL queries in ADO.NET as suggested by Garrison Neely in a comment. What I was trying to do here is not feasible with the `SqlDataSource` class.